# Which of the two formulae should I take as the initial kinetic energy of the system to find the stopping distance in a perfectly inelastic collision?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, collision

A simple exercise in classical mechanic:

> A ball of mass $m$ and initial speed $v$ collides with a block of mass $M$ at rest. The coefficient of kinetic friction between the block and the ground is $\mu$ and there is no fiction between the ball and the ground. Given that the collision is perfectly inelastic (i.e. the ball sticks to the block), what is the stopping distance $d$?

My original thought process:

By conservation of momentum, the speed of the block and the ball after collision is $\dfrac{mv}{m+M}$. Thus, using the work-energy theorem, $\mu(m+M)gd=\dfrac{1}{2}(m+M)\left(\dfrac{mv}{m+M}\right)^2$. Solving it give $d=\dfrac{1}{2\mu g}\left(\dfrac{mv}{m+M}\right)^2$

However, the solution given by the textbook wrote:

By the work-energy theorem, $\mu(m+M)gd=\dfrac{1}{2}mv^2$, solving it give $d=\dfrac{1}{2\mu g}\left(\dfrac{mv^2}{m+M}\right)$

With no further explanation, I am puzzled by why the textbook takes $\dfrac{1}{2}mv^2$ as the initial kinetic energy of the system instead of $\dfrac{1}{2}(m+M)\left(\dfrac{mv}{m+M}\right)^2$. Since some of the kinetic energy could be converted as heat during collision, I think we should apply the work-energy theorem **after** the ball and the block stick together and become a single object, rather than **before**.

My question is:

> Which of the two formulae should I take as the initial kinetic energy of the system, $\dfrac{1}{2}mv^2$ or $\dfrac{1}{2}(m+M)\left(\dfrac{mv}{m+M}\right)^2$?

Comment: there is an ambiguity: is the frictionless ball's mass supported by the surface post-collision, or does it go through "M" and add to $\mu$'s effect?

Comment: @JEB No, it is not specified.

Comment: It's not the problem anyway, since the1st  answer points out that the book made a mistake. The point of my answer is that sticking with momentum and skipping velocity, in my opinion, is simpler...since momentum is what is conserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That textbook solution is incorrect.  Energy is not conserved during inelastic collisions, and so equating the initial kinetic energy of the ball to the work done by friction is inappropriate.  Your solution correctly waits to apply conservation of energy until after applying conservation of momentum.

You should check to see if your textbook has errata which are posted somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This simple exercise is proposed in the remark following the solution to problem 5.20 in David Morin's Introduction to Classical Mechanics: With Problems and Solutions. It is not mentioned in the [newest errata](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/david-morin/files/corrections.pdf) published by the author. I am considering whether to email the author on this error.

Answer (score 1):

Do we really need velocity here?... I mean after starting with the initial (conserved) momentum of the system:

$$ p_i = mv $$

Then momentum conservation is:

$$ p_f = p_i\equiv p $$

while the Work Energy Theory says:

$$ T_f = \frac{p^2}{2(M+m)} = Fd = \mu g(M+m)d$$

so:

$$ d = \frac{p^2}{2\mu g(M+m)^2} $$